# Track online users in real time in order to play a two-player quiz

Tags: real-time, comet, multiplayer

I am willing to create a two-player quiz game, in real time. For this I need to track when users are on my quiz's page and when they leave it. Basically, I need some kind of lobby, where players gather and from where my script picks two random players who should face each other in the game.

As many players would switch from online to offline in a very short time, I prefer not to use the classic 'update player status to database and then retrieve at a given interval the list of online players'. Currently, I am toying with the idea of using Comet Push, and have studied a little bit PubNub.

The actual quiz game I believe it is pretty easy to solve: use of classic Comet publish() to send answers and subscribe() to check the other user's status. But the thing that bothers me is how do I get that specific list with online users?

I tried to publish() a user_id when a user goes to the lobby, but how do I notify all the other users when this user goes offline? How do I display in the lobby the total number of connected users together with their names?

It's the first time I face Comet and its logic isn't entirely clear to me.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try out [Pusher](http://pusher.com) and our (I work for Pusher) [presence functionality](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_channels#subscribe-presence-channels). The presence channels let you easily implement room/lobby-style functionality and should meet your criteria.

- You get an initial list of users subscribed to the channel when you subscribed
- You are informed whenever a user subscribes (enters) and unsubscribes (leaves) the channel (room/lobby)

This way you don't need to implement this functionality yourself. It's part of the solution Pusher provides.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'd rather develop a solution by myself or use a free solution, as I don't want to spend money for this functionality (it is a personal project).

Comment: @linkyndy - I've listed a whole bunch of real-time technologies on the following page, including a self-hosting section, so hopefully it'll be of some use: http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide If presence is important, as it appears to be, then you might want to consider and XMPP solution. Unfortunately I've not identified which of the solutions support XMPP on that page yet though.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll probably stick to PubNub right now, as I have already made some research on how to use it. WebSockets look pretty awesome and I'll definitely use them as fast as they will be widely supported.